# Last 2 letters of the uri defining the used language

Tags: php, expressionengine

```
<?php
$pageurl = "http://".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$pageurl_noslashes = str_replace("/","",$pageurl);
$lang = substr($pageurl_noslashes,-3);
echo $lang;
?>
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" limit="10"}
<p>Product title: <span>{if title<?php echo $lang; ?>} {title<?php echo $lang; ?>} {if:else} {title} {/if}</span></p>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I am hacking expression engine to return the appropriate language variables.

I am aware that the way I am getting the language code (fr/en/etc...) is far from ideal, which is why I need advice on it :)

What happens:

- host.com/products/item/_fr/ — loads French
- host.com/products/item/_en/ — loads English
- host.com/products/item/ — loads English (after failing the if condition)

So in essence, it does exactly what I want, however I feel that it is not the best way to do it.

Comment: what exactly is the question here?  It seems you have a working solution. Are there specific problems with your code that need to be fixed?

Comment: I just wanted to know if this solution is good enough and if it will create issues further down the line.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get it from the http headers sent by the users browser...

```
echo $_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"];
```

It explains how [here](http://www.phptutorial.info/scripts/languages.php)

Comment: Appreciate the response, however I do not care what language their browser is set to. I start caring about their language preference, after they have selected a language from the drop-down that the site will provide. The issue is reading this language selection from the url (as apposed to retrieving it from a cookie or a session).

Comment: I guess you mean $_GET['field name here']

The field name of the language combobox

Comment: $_GET would require a get-powered form and would do a trick on seo. I'm getting the lang attribute in there via simple anchors.