# Getting the last 2 characters of a URI string

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a filter on my site that drops a list of languages when mouse hover. Each language has an anchor that appends its language key to the last segment of the uri (e.g. ?l=es). I wanna catch the 'es' to set session language accordingly. How can I do this? Best thanks!

Its the same question as tis question which did not result in an accepted answer:

[Last 2 letters of the uri defining the used language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058040/last-2-letters-of-the-uri-defining-the-used-language?rq=1)

Comment: Can you try to explain exactly what you want to achieve? Show us some code maybe!?

Comment: I just wanna know how to get the 'es' when its appended to the last segment of the uri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

um.. I'm not sure i get your question. you can add a form to your website and set form's action to php file and method to GET. then use $_GET['l'] in php file
here is an php example

```
<?php
session_start();
$language = $_GET["l"];
$_SESSION["language"] = $language;
?>
```

now $language have the value es that you need.

Comment: that's `if (isset($_GET['l']))`

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are looking for.

```
<?php
session_start();
$val=$_GET['l'];//es
echo $val;//es
$_SESSION['val']=$val;
```